# Замена местами сгруппированных данных

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

Есть вот такой класс

```
public class User
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public OrgItem orgItem { get; set; }
}
```

Создаю и заполняю список данными

```
var newList = new List<User>();
newList.Add(new User { Name = "elv", orgItem = new OrgItem { Id = 1, Name = "test1" } });
newList.Add(new User { Name = "elv2", orgItem = new OrgItem { Id = 1, Name = "test1" } });
newList.Add(new User { Name = "elv3", orgItem = new OrgItem { Id = 1, Name = "test1" } });
newList.Add(new User { Name = "elv11", orgItem = new OrgItem { Id = 3, Name = "test3" } });
```

Далее , группирую список по **orgItem**

```
var model = newList.GroupBy(x => x.orgItem.Id);
```

В получившемся сгруппированном списке мне необходимо переместить elv3 в группировку с **OrgItem Id=3** и при этом удалить из группировки с Id=1. Как это возможно сделать?

Заранее это сделать не возможно при получении данных, так как при любой замене данных, это всё меняется в БД, что отсекает такое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на тип результата GroupBy: интерфейс `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`, и на IGrouping: `public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement>` : `IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable`

Все завязано на IEnumerable, который не предполагает изменений коллекции. Поэтому если не уйти от типа результата группировки, то задачу не решить.

Ну а найти нужный элемент для операций удаления и вставки можно так:

```
var searchName = "elv3";
var itemId = model.Where(e => e.Any(i => i.Name == searchName)).Single().Key;
var item = model.Single(e => e.Key == itemId).FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == searchName);
```

Получить список без него:

```
var _a = model.Where(e => e.Key == itemId).Single().ToList().Where(e => e.Name != item.Name);
```

Ну а дальше думайте как вам все это передать дальше и в каком типе

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Этот вариант немного лишний по моему в моем решении, а есть ли возможность тогда в самой группировке расставить данные по нужным места, по идее GroupBy поддерживает какие то фильтры?